# Problems when profiling LLM-training using "huggingface/accelerate" to Night system

Tags: nsight, accelerate, deepspeed, nsight-systems

I am learning the Llama model in a multi-node environment using huggingface/accelerate, and if I run it as follows to profile it, the program will die due to a problem with the ssh connection to another node.

```
$ nsys profile accelerate launch train.py -b 1 -m Llama-2-7b-chat-hf -o sgd -t
```

[image: screenshot]

I know it's not an accurate profiling method for multi-node, but I thought at least profiling would work. But I can't connect to other nodes because I used nsys command…

Also, after that, if I don't give the nsys command and just run the application, the application won't work the same issue. Eventually, I have to stop the docker container and run it again to fix the issue… What is it?

Comment: Could you please try if an approach similar to what is described here, https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/UserGuide/index.html#deepspeed, resolves the issue?

Essentially create a bash script and put the `nsys` command in it, make sure to use the `-o` switch and provide a report name using `%p`. So that reports from different ranks do not collide.

Launch huggingface with the `--no_python` option, e.g., `accelerate launch --no_python <bash script>`.
Please report back if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Regarding the second issue, "I have to stop the docker container and run it again to fix the issue...What is it?", please provide details of the error you are getting. Maybe you should open an additional SO question for that.
Are there hanging huggingface processes?

Comment: Thank you for the valuable advice. I will proceed with the modifications following the direction you provided for the first issue, and I will share the results as they become available. As for the second issue, I may have explained it incorrectly. I was referring to an issue where network connectivity problems arise when I execute profiling with the incorrect nsys command sequence. I will look into this further and get back to you.

Comment: I followed your advice and I succeeded! Thank you very much. However, my practice environment has 2 nodes and 4 GPUs each. My expectation is that a total of 2 nsys-reports are created for each node, but in reality, reports have been made for each GPU process (a total of 8). I don't know if this is the right situation, but another question is that Nsys Document recommends using "Nsys recipe" option for Multi-Node Analysis, what is the difference between analyzing individual reports and using Nsys Recipe? Is it simply because it is visually intuitive?

Comment: Yes, by invoking `nsys` that way you should expect to get a report file for each process that is created by the huggingface launcher.

The advantage of using recipes is that the recipe system can automatically process all the provided reports and generate useful insights. Using recipes might ease the burden of analyzing visually multiple reports. It all depends on what information you are interested in extracting from the reports. If you have questions about the recipe system please open a new question on StackOverflow.

I will convert my comment to an answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to create a bash script and put the `nsys` command in it. Make sure to use the `-o/--output` switch and provide a report name using `%p`, that way reports from different ranks will not collide.

Launch the bash script with huggingface using the `--no_python` option, e.g., `accelerate launch --no_python <bash script>`.

These steps are also described at [docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/UserGuide/index.html#deepspeed](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/UserGuide/index.html#deepspeed) for similar parallel job launchers.